# unable to load resources in a jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a web app project which is uploaded and deployed to heroku. Everything works fine except css, js, fonts and image resources.

I have added all of them to the `src/main/webapp/resources` folder as you can see on the image below. http://pbrd.co/1mi9CC4

this is my `applicationContext.xml`

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/mytheme/" /> 

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

    </bean>

    <beans profile="default">
        <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource"/>        
        <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
            </property>
            <property name="jpaProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </beans>

    <beans profile="prod">
        <bean class="java.net.URI" id="dbUrl">
            <constructor-arg value="#{systemEnvironment['DATABASE_URL']}"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
            <property name="url" value="#{ 'jdbc:postgresql://' + @dbUrl.getHost() + ':' + @dbUrl.getPort() + @dbUrl.getPath() }"/>
            <property name="username" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[0] }"/>
            <property name="password" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[1] }"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
            </property>
            <property name="jpaProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <!-- change this to 'verify' before running as a production app -->
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </beans>

</beans>
```

and this is my `home.jsp`

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>Pumperlgsund</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" />">

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script
    src="<c:url value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" />"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js" />"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand">Pumperlgsund</a>
            </div><!--/.navbar-header -->
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a>Sign in</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="/home/register">Create an account</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <form:form action="/home" method="POST"
            commandName="user" cssClass="form-signin ">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
            <form:input path="username" type="text" cssClass="form-control"
                placeholder="Username" required="true" autofocus="true" />
            <form:input path="password" type="password" cssClass="form-control"
                placeholder="Password" required="true" />
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign
                in</button>
        </form:form>
        <!--/. form-signin -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`pom.xml` listed below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hibernate-template</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
            <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.34.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0.34.0</version>
                                    <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

as you can see, I added `<mvc:resources>` in the applicationContext and linked the resources in `home.jsp`. I really don't have any idea what could cause a problem here and I'll appreciate if you could help me solve this issue.

Comment: provide the fully qualified path as /resources/mytheme/.....

Comment: I tried it also but it didn't help. I have used this tutorial to set things up [link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/) but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Do you have the jstl library and all the required spring libraries in your project?

Comment: Also try pageContext mentioned in the link, if problem persists.

Comment: @ Raffaele that should be fine, as I have previously mentioned, I have used the tutorial on the link above the set up resources in the project and you can see there that <c:url> tag has been used. I have also tried this `<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >` but it didn't help.

Comment: `jstl` lib was missing. to be sure, I will post my `pom.xml` so you can see if all is there. I have included the `jstl` lib and tried again, I have also tried the `pageContext` solution but it didn't help. at least I tried this `<link href="http://pumperlgsundmvctest.herokuapp.com/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >` and this solved the isue. for some reason pageContext doesn't retrieve the url ...

Comment: Your pom looks fine. Did it work now?

Answer (score 2):

Have you mapped your DispatcherServlet to "/" (in your web.xml)? If so, you need to add `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` [(doc)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-default-servlet-handler) to your applicationContext.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I had to update the /Procfile in my project and add the options there, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22924017/444991) by [turboemu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2401934/turboemu):

> To add to what what ryanbrainard has said and in case anyone had the same trouble I did. I found that trying to set this flag at the command line had no effect when I deployed, perhaps since I was deploying when performing git push and not deploying a war using the command line.
>
> I had to update the /Procfile in my project and add the options there. So mine then looked like:
>   web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT --path '' target/*.war
>
> This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="classpath*:" />
```

and corresponding section remains same.Thanks.